# Using Python for excel

Tags: python, excel, libraries

I am trying write python function for convert .sdf file to excel and create table with correct columns and right data in right column.
Which python libraries i can use for this?

This is how i get data in sdf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FsC9.png)

And how its need to be converted
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kjDd.png)

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/getting_started.html) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pandas.pydata.org/getting_started.html

See if the above library can help you out :)